# SparkSql get float type field value null from hive table

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I create and import hive table with sqoop and use pyspark to get data. The table is composed by one string field, one int field and several float field. I can get the whole data by hue hive sql query. But while I program with pyspark sql the non-float field can be displayed and the float fields always show null value.
HUE hive sql results:
[image]

zeppelin pyspark output:
[image]

The details of hive table:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the cause. since I import these tables from mysql via sqoop. the original table columns are uppercase and in hive they were converted to all lowercase automatically. it caused all converted fields value can not be retrieved by sparksql. (but HUE hive queries these data normally, It might be a bug of spark.) I have to convert uppercase field names to lower case by specify the option --query in sqoop command. i.e. --query 'select MMM as mmm from table...'